# Did the Allies punish their own war criminals?

Tags: world-war-two, war-crime

[Wiki says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allied_war_crimes_during_World_War_II) "There were a number of war crimes involving Allied personnel that were investigated by the Allied powers and that led in some instances to courts-martial." No citation was given for this statement, however.

Did the allies actually do this? What are some major examples?

Comment: Could you add a link to the Wikipedia page that you quoted? Maybe it has some sources or further explanations that we can look at.

Comment: [Do you have any reason to doubt the assertion?](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/a/642/1401http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/a/642/1401)

Comment: You mean the assertion from the Wikipedia article? Well, when I did my history degree they told me you shouldn't believe everything you read on Wikipedia, particularly if they don't give it a source. Old-fashioned, I know.

Comment: @NeMo While I agree with your point, I think you should also point that out within the text of the question. I edited it in, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not in the least!

Comment: Bringing own people to court-martial for war crimes or other is not that rare, so I think you should be more specific to have more than a trivial "yes" answer.

Answer (score 1):

About 500 US soldiers were condemned to death during WW2 for murder or rape. Of these, 70 were actually executed, the rest being let go after serving short prison terms. No distinction was made between murders which were "war crimes" and criminal murders, but it is likely the large majority of murders and rapes which were prosecuted were of a criminal nature. None of the various major massacres of German prisoners was ever investigated or prosecuted. So, to answer your question there are no "major examples".

Comment: Do you have a source for that 500 number?

Comment: The Dachau Liberation Reprisals were certainly investigated.  Never prosecuted, though:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dachau_liberation_reprisals

Comment: @AlaskaRon Okay, maybe I should written "seriously investigated", if you are going to pick nits. One guy asking a few questions, and filing a secret report is hardly an "investigation". By an investigation, I mean a PUBLIC inquiry by MORE THAN ONE PERSON.

Comment: Could you add sources to this answer?

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudley_W._Morton